# Extending TooltipBase with QucikView cause error: 'sap.m.Popover id is opened by a control which isn't rendered yet."

Tags: sapui5, popover

I extended sap.ui.core.TooltipBase with mouseover event handling with creation of sap.m.QuickView which is attached to some sap.ui.core.Icon:

```
    sap.ui.define(function () {
    "use strict";
    return sap.ui.core.TooltipBase.extend("abc.reuseController.TooltipBase", { 
            metadata: {
                events: {
                    "onmouseover" : {}  
                }
            },
            oView: null,

            setView : function(view){
                this.oView = view;
            },

//          the hover event handler, it is called when the Button is hovered - no event registration required
            onmouseover : function() {
                this._createQuickView();
            },

            _createQuickView: function(){
                var view = this.oView;
                alert("Event mouseover.");

//              create QuickViewGroupElement
                var oQuickViewGroupElement = new sap.m.QuickViewGroupElement();
                oQuickViewGroupElement.setLabel("item");
                oQuickViewGroupElement.setValue("value");

//              create QuickViewGroup
                var oQuickViewGroup = new sap.m.QuickViewGroup();
                oQuickViewGroup.addElement(oQuickViewGroupElement);

//              create QuickViewPage
                var oQuickViewPage = new sap.m.QuickViewPage();
                oQuickViewPage.addGroup(oQuickViewGroup);

//              create QuickView
                var oQuickView = new sap.m.QuickView();
                oQuickView.addPage(oQuickViewPage); 

//              connect QuickView with Button
                oQuickView.openBy(view.byId("filterButton"));                           
            },
        });  
});
```

In my controller I added TooltipBase to sap.ui.core.Icon with id="filterButton":

```
var oTooltipBase = new TooltipBase();           
oTooltipBase.setView(this.getView());   

var oIconFilterButton = this.byId("filterButton");
oIconFilterButton.setTooltip(oTooltipBase);
```

I would like to get QuickView to be shown when I hover over this Icon, which is placed on the ChartContainer in the xml:

```
<suite:customIcons>                 
   <core:Icon id="filterButton" src="sap-icon://drop-down-list" press="onFilterDialogOpen" width="2em"/> 
</suite:customIcons>
```

Hovering over this icon works well, alert("Event mouseover."); is shown, also QuickView is created correctly (I tried the same code on sap.m.Button), but I get error on this line in the sap.ui.core.TooltipBase.extend:

```
oQuickView.openBy(view.byId("filterButton"));
```

[image]

It is from this sap library:

[image]

And this line d = this._getOpenByDomRef(); returns null, but why I have no clue:

[image]

I am not sure if here is somenone who met this issue, but if yes I would be really glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just one issue.

As I mentioned in this below question: [extending-sap-ui-core-icon-with-hover-event-or-mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394131/extending-sap-ui-core-icon-with-hover-event-or-mouseover/41424920), your custom Icon is getting converted into the OverflowButton:

```
sap.suite.ui.commons.ChartContainer.prototype._addButtonToCustomIcons = function(i) {
    var I = i;
    var s = I.getTooltip();
    var b = new sap.m.OverflowToolbarButton({
        icon: I.getSrc(),
        text: s,
        tooltip: s,
        type: sap.m.ButtonType.Transparent,
        width: "3rem",
        press: [{
            icon: I
        }, this._onOverflowToolbarButtonPress.bind(this)]
    });
    this._aCustomIcons.push(b);
}
```

What you probably missed is the fact that Id of your custom Icon is not used and a new auto-generated Id is created for Overflow Button (bad).

Hence, the Overflow button id is not : filterButton but some auto-generated Id.

Here is the solution: Change the code where you are opening QuickView in your custom control:

Previous Code:

```
//              connect QuickView with Button
            oQuickView.openBy(view.byId("filterButton"));
```

Correct Code :

```
//              connect QuickView with Button
                oQuickView.openBy(this.getParent());
```

EDIT: 
In the code:

```
 //              connect QuickView with Button
                    oQuickView.openBy(this.getParent());
```

this refers to your custom tooltip. As tooltip is passed along to OverflowButton ( code above), tooltip parent is The overflow button. Hence, the code: this.getParent().

Also, I would suggest you to set the placement of your view to 'Bottom'. ( default is right and it was causing UI issues).

```
//              create QuickView
                var oQuickView = new sap.m.QuickView({placement:"Bottom"});
                oQuickView.addPage(oQuickViewPage);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Rahul. I thought that when I managed to get view.byId("filterButton") so I can work with that. For me it is quite strange when for example this works:  var oIconFilterButton = this.byId("filterButton"); oIconFilterButton.setTooltip(oTooltipBase); and this does not oQuickView.openBy(view.byId("filterButton")); How can one know that Icon is converted to sap.m.OverflowToolbarButton for example (without debuging core)? I mean some newbie as I am. I understand now after your explanation, why it behaves as it behaves.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help. I'm sure developers would have a logical explanation. But you are right. Its is not straight forward to know that Icons are converted internally. May be they can document changes more. :)

Comment: Rahul, could you please check my new problem with this issue? Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544509/tooltipbaserenderer-js-404-not-found