# TooltipBaseRenderer.js: 404 - NOT FOUND

Tags: sapui5

I extended sap.ui.core.TooltipBase with mouseover event handling which is attached to some sap.ui.core.Icon in the ChartContainer:

```
 sap.ui.define(function () {
    "use strict";
    return sap.ui.core.TooltipBase.extend("dvd.rl.component.ChartContainer.parts.TooltipBase.TooltipBase", { 
            metadata: {
                events: {
                    "onmouseover" : {}  
                }
            },
            oView: null,

            setView : function(view){
                this.oView = view;
            },

//          the hover event handler, it is called when the Button is hovered - no event registration required
            onmouseover : function() {}, 
});
```

Everythink works well, but when I click on the Icon in the ChartContainer I got this error from the TooltipBaseRenderer.js (This happens before handling of press event.):

[image]

In the TooltipBaseRenderer.js it is this line:

[image]

I have no idea what is going on there. If you will have I will be happy to hear it.

This is how I added TooltipBase to sap.ui.core.Icon:

```
//          Add custom Icon for filter
            var oFilterIcon = new  sap.ui.core.Icon("filterButton", {       
                tooltip     : "{i18n>filter}",
                src         : "sap-icon://filter",
                press       : [this.onHandleLocalFilterOpen,this]
            });
//          Add Icon to chart component
            oChartContainer.addCustomIcon(oFilterIcon); 

            var oTooltipBase = new TooltipBase();
//          set new TooltipBase to Icon                 
            oFilterIcon.setTooltip(oTooltipBase);
```

EDITED 12:15 100117:

When I use renderer in the TooltipBase.extend:

```
//just inherit the renderer as it is
renderer: {},
```

I got this error:

[image]

So I removed renderer, and TooltipBase works when I hover over Icon. The problem is when I click on the Icon as I described higher.

Comment: could you create jsfiddle for it, I can debug.

Comment: @ Sunil, thanks for interesting in this issue. Here you can debug https://plnkr.co/edit/h7TQWhN9xQrdo6Aqpnl4?p=preview, but I do not know how to include my TooltipBase.js to the index, so I commented it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working [sample **custom tooltip** extended from `sap/ui/core/TooltipBase`](https://embed.plnkr.co/33zFqa).

Make sure that your renderer has the `render` method. Otherwise UI5 will look for it at the parent. Also `TooltipBase` already handles the mouse events. No need to handle them in your extension.

---

This is what happened:

1. Your renderer had no `render` function (`renderer: { }`).
2. UI5 looks for the `render` in the parent renderer (`sap/ui/core/TooltipBaseRenderer`).
3. There is no `TooltipBaseRenderer.js` since `TooltipBase` is an abstract control. **Abstract controls have no renderer** (`renderer: null // not undefined` in their definition).

Usually, UI5 bypasses fetching the renderer for abstract controls but  the `TooltipBase` was unfortunately missing the `renderer: null`. So UI5 assumed that there must be a file named `TooltipBaseRenderer.js` which resulted in the 404 error. [As of UI5 1.82, the `TooltipBase` has `renderer: null`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/50da9eedc2bf4a024694f2f84dd4c7c13cb2200c#diff-f0413cea2fdf36e81050b085620aedef6f2ab95fc24fb83b7a376883030ba26c), so **the issue is no longer reproducible.**