# SAPUI5 using Popover as a tooltip

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to use the [sap.m.Popover](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Popover.html) as a "rich tooltip" for some controls. This is as per recommendation from SAP because the sap.ui.commons library is now deprecated. We have too much text we want to add to the standard string tooltip. I haven't figured out a way to use the popover directly as a tooltip, which is why I've extended the [TooltipBase](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.TooltipBase.html) control to handle the popover.

I've got the popover working fine, However when I interact with my control, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: failed to load 'myNewToolTip/controls/TooltipBaseRenderer.js' from ../controls/TooltipBaseRenderer.js: 404 - Not Found

I see from these [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544509/tooltipbaserenderer-js-404-not-found) that it is because the TooltipBase class is an abstract class and therefore doesn't have a renderer. However, because I'm already using the popover, I don't need to render anything. I've tried to add the TooltipBaseRenderer.js and just have an empty render class. But UI5 really doesn't like that either.

My question is what should I do, I see two options:

- There is probably a simple way to use the popover as a tooltip, which I'm just too stupid to figure out (Bear in mind, I'd prefer to bind it directly in the XML view).
- Figure out a way to suppress the renderer call as I don't need it.

This is my current source code for the custom control:

```
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/m/Popover"
], function (Popover) {
  "use strict";

  return sap.ui.core.TooltipBase.extend("myNewToolTip.TooltipBase", {
    metadata: {
      properties: {
        title : {}
      },
      events: {
        "onmouseover" : {},
        "onmouseout" : {}
      }
    },

    oView: null,
    setView: function(view) {
      this.oView = view;
    },

    onmouseover : function(oEvent) {
      var that = this;
      if (!this.delayedCall){
        this.delayedCall = setTimeout(function() {
          if (!that.oPopover){
            that._createQuickView();
          }
        }, 500);
      }
    },

    onmouseout: function(oEvent) {
      if (this.oPopover){
        this.closePopover();
        this.delayedCall = undefined;
      }
      else{
        clearTimeout(this.delayedCall);
        this.delayedCall = undefined;
      }
    },

    _createQuickView: function() {
      var sTitle = this.getTitle();
      this.oPopover = new Popover({
        title: sTitle
      });
      this.oPopover.openBy(this.getParent());
    },

    closePopover: function(){
      this.oPopover.close();
      this.oPopover = undefined;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to create a custom control just to display a popover on mouseover. As you said, there is a simpler way: [Adding event delegates](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#addEventDelegate).

One of the [events that delegates can listen to](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/61e3b44693289556eb26f0a9b6d8a11cd170b7cd/src/sap.ui.core/src/jquery.sap.events.js) is `onmouseover` which can be achieved like this:

```js
this.byId("myTargetControl").addEventDelegate({
  onmouseover: function () {
    // Open popover here
  }
});
```

**Demo:** https://embed.plnkr.co/jAFIHK

[image: sap.m.Popover on mouseover]

---

## Extending `sap.ui.core.TooltipBase`

If you still consider extending TooltipBase (without Popover), take a look at this **example:** https://embed.plnkr.co/33zFqa?show=control/MyCustomTooltip.js,preview

[image]

---

Keep in mind, though, that tooltips in general shouldn't contain critical information due to its lack of discoverability as [Fiori Design Guideline mentions](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/using-tooltips/#responsiveness-and-adaptiveness)

> Tooltips (...) should never contain critical information. They should also not contain redundant information.

Just as a friendly reminder :) Don't make people hover to find things.