# how to display formatted text containing html tags using RichTooltip in UI5

Tags: sapui5

I want to set tooltip text for each grid of table in UI5 using RichTooltip control. Also I want the text to be proper formatted like if text containing bold or italic html tags, then it should display the data in same fashion. E.g.: `text="<b>hello</b> <i>world</i>"` should display `hello` in bold and `world` in italics.

Comment: first just clear my doubt is it possible to do it through RichTooltip control or is there any other control in ui5?

Comment: Yes you can do it using `<core:HTML>` control where you can render your  HTML using [HTML Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_4.asp). You can refer [sap.ui.core.HTML](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.Html/preview)

Answer (score 1):

[RichTooltip](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.commons.RichTooltip) should not be used anymore since its library `sap.ui.commons` is deprecated. Instead, go for the [Popover](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Popover). You can combine Popover with `onmouseover` if you really have to. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45490191/5846045

Nevertheless, hiding information behind the mouseover event is considered bad practice in terms of UX because of [poor accessibility](https://medium.com/salesforce-ux/7-things-every-designer-needs-to-know-about-accessibility-64f105f0881b#8e05) and low [discoverability](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/using-tooltips/#responsiveness-and-adaptiveness):

> Tooltips are limited to desktop devices. [...] They should never contain critical information. They should also not contain redundant information.

Toolitps should only be used to present a tiny explanatory content. Approaches like "rich" tooltips, however, encourage developers to hide relevant information.

---

To display formatted text, you can use the control [FormattedText](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.FormattedText) or [HTML](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.HTML):

```js
sap.ui.require([
  "sap/m/FormattedText",
  "sap/ui/core/HTML"
], function(FormattedText, HTML) {

  new FormattedText({
    htmlText: "<strong>Hello</strong> <em>world</em>"
  }).placeAt("content");

  new HTML({
    content: "<b>Hello</b> <i>world</i>"
  }).placeAt("content");

});
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"></script>
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content"></body>
```

**Note:** In an XMLView, the character `<` has to be escaped with `&lt;`.

Comment: thanks a lot, it cleared all my doubt related to this topic

Comment: Can anyone help me in getting the exact difference between using Popover and Callout control for displaying tooltip. I will be much thankful for detailed explanation regarding this concept in terms of processing and performance wise

Comment: @anitab Better open a separate question for this. But *IMO*, because of maintenance costs, deprecated controls (such as RichTooltips and [Callout](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.commons.Callout)) should be avoided even if they're slightly better than x in any way.

Comment: @anitab anything else I could help? Otherwise, please accept any answer to inform others that the problem is now solved. You can also post and accept your own answer if you found a better solution that helped you further. Btw.: If you still consider using *RichTooltip*, you can also extend [TooltipBase](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.TooltipBase) and create your own *"RichTooltip"* instead of depending on the deprecated sap.ui.commons library. E.g.: https://embed.plnkr.co/33zFqa/