# sap.m.MenuItem sapui5 attacheventbrowser does not work

Tags: sapui5, mouseover

trying to attach "onmouseover" event handler to sap.m.MenuItem sapui5 using attachBrowserEvent but I get

> Item.attachBrowserEvent is not a function error

here is the code I have tried - Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
            var item1 = new sap.m.MenuItem({
                text: "item1",
                press: ()=> {
                    //do somethign                    }
            });

            var item2 = new sap.m.MenuItem({
                text: "item2",
                enabled: false,
            });

            item2.attachBrowserEvent("mouseover", function(){
                const oPopover = new sap.m.Popover({
                   showHeader: false,
                   placement: sap.m.PlacementType.HorizontalPreferredRight,
                   contentWidth: "500px",
                   content: [
                    new sap.m.Text({
                        text: "item2 is deactived"
                    })
                ]
            });
            item2.attachBrowserEvent("mouseover", function() {
                oPopover.openBy(item2);
            });
            item2.attachBrowserEvent("mouseout", function() {
                oPopover.close();
            });
                                        });
            var oMenu = new sap.m.Menu({
                items: [item1,item2]

            })
```

Comment: If you need to display some content on _mouseover_ other than just text, extending `sap.ui.core.TooltipBase` might be a better option since every element supports the aggregation `tooltip` but not `attachBrowserEvent`. Take a look at this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45490191/](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45490191/5846045)

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the control sap.m.MenuItem has no such function. To look up all functions of the controll look in the API: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/api/sap.m.MenuItem

BUT a sap.m.MenuItem inherits the function "attachEvent" from sap.ui.base.EventProvider:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/api/sap.ui.base.EventProvider/methods/attachEvent

I think that s what you are looking for.

Hope this is of help to you,
Eric