# SAPUI5 Custom MessagePopoverItem Template

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a custom SAPUI5 application that used SAPUI5 version 1.40.11.
Since this version has been removed from CDN recently, I had to use a long-term maintenance available compatible version for the app. It is - version - 1.38.55.

I'm having an issue with MessagePopoverItem as the subtitle property is not available for this version.
So I'm trying to customize the template of the MessagePopoverItem to display the subtitle field.

While I'm trying to do this via a custom control I received the following error as it looks for a renderer.js from CDN without looking at it from the local location.

> Cannot load from
> https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.55/resources/sap/m/MessagePopoverItemRenderer.js

This is my custom controller and it's renderer.js
And I followed the below link
[TooltipBaseRenderer.js: 404 - NOT FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544509/tooltipbaserenderer-js-404-not-found)

```
    sap.ui.define([
    "sap/m/MessagePopoverItem",
    "./CustomMessagePopupItemRender",
], function (MessagePopoverItem,CustomMessagePopupItemRender) {
    "use strict";
    return MessagePopoverItem.extend("demoapp.customControls.CustomMessagePopoverItem", {
        renderer:CustomMessagePopupItemRender,
        metadata : {
            properties: {
                subtitle: {
                    type: "string",
                    defaultValue: ""
                }
            }
        },
        onAfterRendering: function() {
            if(MessagePopoverItem.prototype.onAfterRendering) {
                MessagePopoverItem.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            //...check if there is a highlight and tooltip
            if(this.getTitle() !== "") {
                sapMLIBContent
                var oHl = this.$().find(".sapMLIBContent");
                var ss = oHl;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Renderer.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/Renderer",
  ], function(Renderer) {
    "use strict";
  
    return Renderer.extend("demoapp.customControls.CustomMessagePopupItemRender", {
      apiVersion: 2,
      render: function(renderManager, control) {
        // Issue: render function is called twice.
        // See: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3169
        // Update: fixed since 1.88
  
        const child = control.getAggregation("content");
        if (child && child.isA("sap.ui.core.Control")) {
          renderManager.openStart("div", control)
            .accessibilityState(control, { role: "tooltip" })
            .style("max-width", "95vw")
            .style("width", control.getWidth())
            .openEnd()
            .renderControl(child)
            .close("div");
        } else {
          renderManager.openStart("span", control)
            .accessibilityState(control, { role: "tooltip" })
            .style("max-width", "90vw")
            .style("width", control.getWidth())
            .style("padding", "0.5rem")
            .class("sapThemeBaseBG-asBackgroundColor")
            .openEnd()
            .text(control.getText())
            .close("span");
        }
      },
  
    });
  });
```

Is this possible to customize the item template of the MessagePopover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to extend the sap.m.MessagePopoverItem as mentioned by @Boghyon Hoffmann.

Here's the answer

CustomMessagePopoverItem.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/m/MessagePopoverItem",
], function (MessagePopoverItem) {
    "use strict";
    return MessagePopoverItem.extend("demoapp.customControls.CustomMessagePopoverItem", {
        metadata : {
            properties: {
                subtitle: {
                    type: "string",
                    defaultValue: ""
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

CustomMessagePopover.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/m/MessagePopover",
    "sap/m/StandardListItem",
    "sap/ui/core/IconPool",
    "./CustomMessagePopoverItem"
], function (MessagePopover,StandardListItem,IconPool,CustomMessagePopoverItem) {
    "use strict";
    var MessagePopover = MessagePopover.extend("demoapp.customControls.CustomMessagePopover", {
        metadata : {
            aggregations: {
                /**
                 * A list with message items
                 */
                items: {type: "demoapp.customControls.CustomMessagePopoverItem", multiple: true, singularName: "item"},

            },

        },
        //Override following method to add the subtitle as the description of the Standard List Item
        _mapItemToListItem :function (oMessagePopoverItem) {
            if (!oMessagePopoverItem) {
                return null;
            }
    
            var sType = oMessagePopoverItem.getType(),
                oListItem = new StandardListItem({
                    title: oMessagePopoverItem.getTitle(),
                    icon: this._mapIcon(sType),
                    description :oMessagePopoverItem.getSubtitle(),
                    type: sap.m.ListType.Navigation
                }).addStyleClass(CSS_CLASS + "Item").addStyleClass(CSS_CLASS + "Item" + sType);
    
            oListItem._oMessagePopoverItem = oMessagePopoverItem;
    
            return oListItem;
        }

        
    });

    var CSS_CLASS = "sapMMsgPopover",
            ICONS = {
                back: IconPool.getIconURI("nav-back"),
                close: IconPool.getIconURI("decline"),
                information: IconPool.getIconURI("message-information"),
                warning: IconPool.getIconURI("message-warning"),
                error: IconPool.getIconURI("message-error"),
                success: IconPool.getIconURI("message-success")
            },
            LIST_TYPES = ["all", "error", "warning", "success", "information"],
            // Property names array
            ASYNC_HANDLER_NAMES = ["asyncDescriptionHandler", "asyncURLHandler"],
            // Private class variable used for static method below that sets default async handlers
            DEFAULT_ASYNC_HANDLERS = {
                asyncDescriptionHandler: function (config) {
                    var sLongTextUrl = config.item.getLongtextUrl();
                    if (sLongTextUrl) {
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: sLongTextUrl,
                            success: function (data) {
                                config.item.setDescription(data);
                                config.promise.resolve();
                            },
                            error: function() {
                                var sError = "A request has failed for long text data. URL: " + sLongTextUrl;
                                jQuery.sap.log.error(sError);
                                config.promise.reject(sError);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };

    


    
});
```

Here I invoke the custom control from the controller

```
var oMessageTemplate = new demoapp.customControls.CustomMessagePopoverItem({
                type: '{TYPE}',
                title: 'My Title',
                description: '{DESC}', 
                subtitle: '{DESC}' 
            });


            var oMessagePopover2 = new demoapp.customControls.CustomMessagePopover({
                items: {
                    path: '/Messages',
                    template: oMessageTemplate
                }
            });
```

Comment: This is great. Please keep in mind to switch to the standard [`sap.m.MessageItem`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.MessageItem) as soon as it's available. The `MessagePopover`'s private method `_mapItemToListItem` won't be existing anymore in later versions. Unfortunately, `MessagePopover` doesn't seem to provide any APIs that the extensions can overwrite reliably.

Answer (score 2):

[TooltipBaseRenderer.js: 404 - NOT FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544509/tooltipbaserenderer-js-404-not-found) is a completely different issue than the issue in this question. The element `sap.m.MessagePopoverItem` which [extends `sap.ui.core.Item`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.Element), is **not** a `sap.ui.core.Control` but an `sap.ui.core.Element`. It is **not supposed to have a renderer** by definition.

`sap.ui.core.TooltipBase`, on the other hand, **is** a `sap.ui.core.Control`. It's a different issue.

Instead, you'll have to:

- Extend `sap.m.MessagePopoverItem` by the `subTitle` property but **without a renderer** since it's not a control.
- Extend the control that actually renders items using the information from your extended `MessagePopoverItem` element.